# custom radio input after quiz submit (posted code)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm completing this interesting code that shows a multiple choice quiz with submit button to the end with a ClassList.toggle (correct) and (wrong). After click the submit quiz feature, the correct answers are shown in green and the wrong ones in red. Now, how to customize the radio input as in the attached image to show after the submit?

[image]

```html
<form id="quiz">
<div class="questions">
    
    <dl id="lezione1">

    <dd><b>1. QUESTION.</b><br>      
    <table id="myTable1">
    <tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1a"> 1. ERRATA</label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1b"> 2. CORRETTA</label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1c"> 3. ERRATA</label></td></tr>
    </table>
    <hr></dd>
    
    <dd><b>2. QUESTION.</b><br>
    <table id="myTable2">
    <tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="2a"> 1. CORRETTA</label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="2b"> 2. ERRATA</label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="2c"> 3. ERRATA</label></td></tr>
    </table>
    <hr></dd>
    
    
   
</div>
</form>


<style>
.correct {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.error {
  color: red;
  fontSize = "larger";
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
</style>



<script>
var answers = ["1b","2a","3a","4a","5a"];
var rads, quiz; // need to be set after load
window.addEventListener("load",function() { // when page loads
  quiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
  rads = quiz.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]"); // all radios in the quiz
  document.getElementById("scoreButton").addEventListener("click",function(e) { // on click of scoreme
    var score = 0;
    for (var i=0;i<rads.length;i++) { // loop over all radios in the form
      var rad = rads[i];
      var idx = rad.name.substring(1)-1; //remove the q from the name - JS arrays start at 0
      var checked = rad.checked;
      var correct = rad.value==answers[idx];
      
      if (correct) {
        rad.closest("label").classList.toggle("correct");
        if (checked) score +=1;
      }  
      else if (checked) {
        score +=0;
        rad.closest("label").classList.toggle("error")
      }  
    }
    var scoreper = Math.round(score * 100 / rads.length);
    document.querySelector("#percentage").innerHTML = scoreper + "%";
    quiz.mark.value = score;
  });  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var answers = ["1b","2a","3a"];
var rads, quiz; // need to be set after load
window.addEventListener("load",function() { // when page loads
  quiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
  rads = quiz.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]"); // all radios in the quiz
  document.getElementById("scoreButton").addEventListener("click",function(e) { // on click of scoreme
    var score = 0;
    for (var i=0;i<rads.length;i++) { // loop over all radios in the form
      var rad = rads[i];
      var idx = rad.name.substring(1)-1; //remove the q from the name - JS arrays start at 0
      var checked = rad.checked;
      var correct = rad.value==answers[idx];
      
      if (correct) {
        rad.closest("label").classList.toggle("correct");
        if (checked) score +=1;
      }  
      else if (checked) {
        score +=0;
        rad.closest("label").classList.toggle("error")
      }  
    }
    var scoreper = Math.round(score / (rads.length / 3) * 100);
    document.querySelector("#percentage").innerHTML = scoreper + "%";
    quiz.mark.value = score;
  });  
});
```

```css
.correct {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.error {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}


/* pretty radio */
label > input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
label > input[type="radio"] + *::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  margin-left: -1.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.1rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.1rem;
  border-color: gray;
}
label > input[type="radio"]:checked + * {
  color: teal;
  
}
label > input[type="radio"]:checked + *::before {
  background: radial-gradient(teal 0%, teal 40%, transparent 50%, transparent);
  border-color: teal;
}

/* basic layout */
label > input[type="radio"] + * {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0rem 0rem;
}
```

```html
<form id="quiz">
<div class="questions">
    
    <dl id="lezione1">

    <dd><b>1. DOMANDA.</b><br>      
    <table id="myTable1">
    <tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1a"><span></span>1. wrong</label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1b"><span></span>2. right</label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1c"><span></span>3. wrong</label></td></tr>
    </table>
    <hr></dd>
    
    <dd><b>2. DOMANDA.</b><br>
    <table id="myTable2">
    <tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="2a"><span></span>1. right</label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="2b"><span></span>2. wrong</label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="2c"><span></span>3. wrong</label></td></tr>
    </table>
    <hr></dd>

    <dd><b>3. DOMANDA.</b><br>
    <table id="myTable3">
    <tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="3a"><span></span>1. CORRETTA</label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="3b"><span></span>2. ERRATA</label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="3c"><span></span>3. ERRATA</label></td></tr>
    </table>
    <hr></dd>
</dl>

      <input type="button" value="VERIFICA" id="scoreButton"><br><br>
      <input type="reset" value="Clear"><br> 
      Risposte esatte = <input type="text" size="5" id="mark"><br>
      Percentuale  = <span id="percentage"></span>

</div>
</form>
```